# SSD Issue - TRIM related?

Tags: ssd, trim

I'd bought an SSD that I'd put in my early 2011 13" MBP to make a DIY Fusion Drive in conjunction with the original 500GB HDD. A few weeks ago, I enabled TRIM (using TRIM Enabler). 5 days later, [the SSD totally died.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/159257/85884) Now, I know correlation doesn't imply causation, but could enabling TRIM be what broke the SSD so much so that even a total reformat (which I've attempted to no avail) couldn't fix it? And if so, how do I un-TRIM it?

For those of you who don't want to look at the link to my past question, basically my SSD was working fine until one day my computer became unbearably slow and then hung every time I tried to reinstall OS X 10.10.1. Disk Utility said the disks were okay, but the install would never work. My computer's working fine now because I'm running entirely on the HDD.

Comment: and you are on Yosemite ? and is that the original apple ssd?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm on 10.10.1, and I bought the SSD from Intel. The computer came with a 500GB HDD.

Comment: thanks, by dead SSD you mean ? can you run any test ?

Comment: it still could be that the stupid Yosemite is blocking it because of Trim. If you know how, disable it and restart without the Trim.

Comment: @Buscar웃 By "dead" I mean the attempted OS reinstall would hang every time. And I don't know how to disable Trim.

Comment: TRIM is enabled by adjusting an OS file.  If you are booting from another system [USB] drive or from a fresh OS install on the HDD, it won't be enabled.  If you are still having problems with the SSD, it is either a problem with the drive itself or the 2nd drive bay.  See the [OWC blog](http://blog.macsales.com/11895-2011-macbook-pro-sata-problems-resolved) about the 2nd drive bay problem.

Comment: Do you actually have a lots of I/O in your console?